# How to retrieve the Id of a single Firestore document?

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

This is my code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFirestore
       , AngularFirestoreCollection
       , AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

interface Country {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  code?: string;
  flag?: string;
  continent?: string;
}


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Firestore - Documents';

    private countryRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Country>;
    docId: any;

    constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore ) {

        this.countryRef = this.afs.collection('Country', ref => ref.where('code', '==', 'za'));

        this.docId = this.countryRef.snapshotChanges().map( changes => {
            return changes.map(a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Country;
                data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data.id;
            });
        });

    console.log(this.docId);

  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

I am expecting an ugly firestore id but instead I am getting this:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

Answer (score 14):

You are getting data as Observable `const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Country`

you need to subscribe to get the data

```
this.docId.subscribe(docs => {
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id);
  })
})
```

Here is the recommended way to do it

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'Firestore - Documents';

private countryRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Country>;
docId: Observable<Country[]>;

constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore ) {

    this.countryRef = this.afs.collection('Country', ref => ref.where('code', '==', 'za'));

    this.docId = this.countryRef.snapshotChanges().map( changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Country;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
        });
    });

this.docId.subscribe(docs => {
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id);
  })
})

}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Most common practice to retrieve data from firestore using angularfire2 are `.valueChanges()` and `.snapshotChanges()`. valueChanges() method provides only the data. It strips all meta data including `keys`. On other hand .snapshotChanges() will return all data including metadata.

In your code when you do `const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Country;` it only returns the data with out key. and when you map it to `const data` id will be ignored because you specified your constructor like `id?: string;` null safe mode.

Then you get the id `const id = a.payload.doc.id;` and somehow you need to return it the way you want your `interface` is. By doing this `return { id, ...data };` you are returning all data with id too. and `...data` will append all its field one by one after id. you can learn more about this feature [here](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/02/features-of-es6-part-5-the-spread.aspx) Hope you understand.

Comment: Hi Hareesh.  Thank you so much.  It worked like a charm.

Comment: Hi Hareesh. Would it be to much to ask to please explain the ...data.  I have never seen that before.

Comment: Thank you Hareesh.  Makes sense to me now.

Comment: How could I get an user document having inside `Country` his `userId`?

Comment: @DanielRodriguez i didn't get your question. please ask a new question with a detailed explanation about your problem. also post it under angularfire2, firebase tags.

Comment: What I mean is, imaging that the `Country` is created by some user so we'd have a reference to his id on the country document. I'd like to display my country but also the users name.
More info and question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49860360/get-user-info-with-userid-angular-firestore/49862115?noredirect=1#comment86813223_49862115