# How to get UID from an Angular fire store Document without snapshot

Tags: firebase, angularfire, angularfire2, angularfire5

let say I have a collection named `Countries` and a doc looks like below

```
{
  name: "Pakistan"
  //other field removed to focus on problem only
}
```

and a Collection names `Cities` which doc have above country field reference looks like

```
{
  name: "Karachi",
  //other field removed to focus on problem only
  city: "3FbRFiWB4DmfdcxDdei3" //reference of country document
}
```

now I am displaying the countries and cities as ordered drop down menus as user select country then the next drop down displays filtered cities

```
let countryRef = this.angularFireStore.collection('Countries', ref => ref);
let countries = countryRef.valueChanges();
```

and html binding looks like

```
let country of country | async"
```

Here is the actual problem on any change or select event of user I have to pass id of country to populated filtered cities based of selected country but I can't got id in country. How to achieve this
any help will be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** I know I can got id and other metadata by getting snapshot change but that response very late I just want id field in reference binding for editing or updating Documents.

Comment: use `.snapshotChanges()` instead of `countryRef.valueChanges();`. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221248/how-to-retrieve-the-id-of-a-single-firestore-document/47223346#47223346). Another option would be save the id with the country doc while creating it.

Comment: @Hareesh thanks one more thing, how can I update query ref dynamically when country field selected. i.e `this.angularFireStore.collection('Cities', ref => ref.where('country', '==', 'selectedcountryID'));`

Comment: @Hareesh `.snapshotChanges()` is very slow other wise I will go with it, didn't you read my `Note` section

Comment: you can use select options change event `<select (change)="countryChanged(selectedcountryID)">` and run the query inside this function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said you don't want to use `.snapshotChanges()` and get id with `.valueChanges()` you need to store it while creating the doc. Do this in your add country function

```
this.tempId = this.angularFireStore.createId();

const newCountry = {
      id:this.tempId,
      name:'Karachi'
      //other fields...
    }

this.angularFireStore.collection('Countries').doc(this.tempId).set(newCountry).then(res => {
  console.log('country added')
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('error adding country',err)
});
```