# Get user info with userId - Angular Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got 2 different collections:

- Users: name, email and avatar (taken from their social network)
- Recipes: documents that the user can create. It also contains `userId` with their references to previous collection

To display these recipes on my page I use:

```
this.recipes = collection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => ({
        $id: action.payload.doc.id,
        ...action.payload.doc.data()
      }));
    });
```

And:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let recipe of recipes | async; let i = index">
...
```

What's the best way to get also the user avatar and name?

Answer (score 0):

For each recipe, you have a userId.  Use that to retrieve the user document for each recipe.  (probably cache users if they show up more than once in the list.)
Remember that the document retrieval is asynchronous so you may want to create an array of promises and use Promise.all https://stackoverflow.com/a/47554838/179156

Comment: how can I get the same user just once?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "get the same user just once".  I was trying to say that the logic might be: Loop through the recipes.  For each recipe, check the user and ID and see if we have that user information cached, if so, return that, else make a DB call to retrieve the user.  (Then add the user to the cache.). Does that make more sense and/or answer the question?

Comment: ok yes, it does but how can I integrate that query (to get the user info) inside my `snapshotChanges`? The `querySnapshots` you linked doesn't have a `collection`, does it change something?

Comment: One straightforward way is subscribe to the observable.  i.e. `collection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => ({
        $id: action.payload.doc.id,
        ...action.payload.doc.data()
      }));
    }).subscribe(recipes => { this.recipies = recipes });`                                    Then you have 'this.recipies' as an array of recipes and you can then loop over the array to get users the users.  (Also remove the async pipe from the HTML side.).  (It's hard to see in this comment, but the change was to add a subscribe to the end of the observable.)

Comment: but I already have that on `.map` if I do a `.subscribe` that's gonna iterate over that object again. Also I need to remove the `For` also on my HTML. Let me have a workaround to see if it's possible to have this without an extra function

Comment: You should be able to subscribe after the .map().  Why do you care if there is an extra function or call?  Unless you are iterating thousands of times, it's not going to amount to anything.

Comment: Not sure if I know how to get these users... What I did was created another reference to the other collection and repeat the same process but I'd also to do another loop to integrate the users inside my recipes, right? But I'd end up with 2 `snapshotChanges`, 2 `snapshotChanges` and an extra loop to create the final object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
this.recipes = collection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    //this.afs.collection('users') is the ref to users collection, yours should be different
    return this.afs.collection('users').doc(data.userId).snapshotChanges().map(userActions=>{
      return userActions.payload.data();
    }).map(user=>{
      return { id:id, userName:user.name, ...data };
    })
  });
}).flatMap(merge => Observable.combineLatest(merge)).map(data => {
  return [].concat(...data).map(d => {
    return d;
  })
});
```